# when i try to open VSTS task through VS2017, Date is visible but time is not visible

Tags: azure-devops

I have VSTS tasks, when I try to open this through VS 2017 only date is visible but time is not visible. In VSTS I can see both time and date.
Can you please help me out.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmN7z.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsK9Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

It should caused by the way VS handles date/time type, and I reported the issue in developer community:

[VSTS datetime work item field does not show time in Visual Studio (compatibility mode)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/326058/vsts-datetime-work-item-field-does-not-show-time-i.html)

You can follow up there.